# Which registers can be modified with PIN_GetContextReg and PIN_SetContextReg

Tags: instrumentation, intel-pin

I want to use PIN_GetContextReg to get the value of register then change it and put it back using PIN_SetContextReg. The PIN manual says that I can do that with to an integer register but all the registers I try other than REG_INST_PTR give an error (Register ** is NOT supported for PIN_GetContextReg/PIN_SetContextReg )

Here is the code

```
    UINT32 old_val;
    UINT32 new_val;
    old_val = PIN_GetContextReg(ctxt,   REG_EAX);       
    new_val = old_val ^ mask;
    PIN_SetContextReg(ctxt,  REG_EAX, new_val);         
    PIN_RemoveInstrumentation();
    PIN_ExecuteAt(ctxt);
```

In this case am trying with register EAX and I get the same error. I am using Pin 3.0

Comment: Could you show us a minimal code that reproduce you problem? also, which version of pin are you using? Usually, all "physical" registers accessible from user mode code should work...

Comment: I am using Pin 3.0 and I have added the minimal code

Comment: The code by itself looks ok. In which way is it called? It should be called in a callback function (i.e from `PIN_AddThreadStartFunction`, `PIN_AddContextChangeFunction` or one of the more usual functions that take a `IARG_CONTEXT` parameter like `INS_InsertCall` or `RTN_InsertCall`).

Comment: I am calling it using **INS_InsertCall** . The error is that PIN_GetContextReg cannot be used for all registers.

Comment: Please post as well the part of the code that sets the instrumentation, as it is often tricky to get right.

Comment: I guess it is about this: PIN_SetContextReg, PIN_SetContextRegval and PIN_SetContextFPState will work only on registers that are in the outSet.  You can read the Doc here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__INST__ARGS.html

Comment: I think you can refer to codes at github for some hints https://github.com/search?q=PIN_SetContextReg&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar problem recently, and get the same error like you.

The problem we both met, I believe, was: our computer have a hardware register called RAX, and EAX is just part of it. As you can see at the last lines in the example below

```
// change eax
PIN_SetContextReg(ctxtTo, REG_RAX,0xbaadf00d);
```

After fix this, my program works! If you need my code as reference, feel free to ask:) 
And the screenshot below comes from https://studylib.net/doc/10207218/verdana-bold-30

[image]